# Installing Android ADT on Eclipse fails due to missing requirements

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, eclipse

I want to install Android ADT on Eclipse. After installing, I get an error and it says that this progress could not be completed. My OS is Ubuntu.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 

(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 

(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759) requires 
'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: Are you running Eclipse Version 3.6.2 or higher?

Comment: i'm using Version: 3.8.0 of eclipse